# how to resize object with additive styles applied to it, while keeping it's copies in place?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

What I want to do is shown here at 0:52, unfortunatelly there is no explanation in the video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Fh-9Ajs0ck

The author applies additive style to a square to acquire a square of 10x10 squares, then resizes all of them by resizing the initial one and gets multiple smaller squares with a margin between them (margin comes from resizing).

When I try to reproduce this effect all my copies move closer to the initial square like additive style is reapplied to my resized square, thus making a new square, consisting of 10x10 square with no margins between them.

Answer (score 1):

There are two very similar graphic styles, and you happened to choose the *other* one. But you're not going to get a handle on this or make it a useful part of your skill set unless you understand what's actually happening here.

This graphic style is just a combination of two Transform effects, one vertical and one horizontal. To understand how it works, create a 150 px square in a new document, then use `Effect > Distort and Transform > Transform` to create a horizontal or vertical transform with 10 copies spaced 200 px apart on centers.

[image]

Close the dialog and use the Free Transform tool to play with the square. Remember that this is the only "real" object. All the copies are just a live effect until you choose `Object > Expand Appearance`.

Once you're confident that you've grasped how this works, add a second Transform effect via the Appearance panel, this time on the other axis. This two step process is how the original "Additive" graphic style was created. It gives you two sets of "ghost" copies that are adjustable both in the size of the basic shape *and* the amount the copies are spaced apart.

You can apply any of the built-in graphic styles in Illustrator and deconstruct it in the Appearance Panel. It's a useful learning tool, and knowing how these styles are created will give you the knowledge you need to be able to create your own.